# Why my cup is black when I turn the transmission to 1 for making glass in blender using eevee?

Tags: materials, eevee-render-engine, transparency, glass

[image]

Following through [this Blender Guru tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7w-m13ykLN8&list=PLjEaoINr3zgEq0u2MzVgAaHEBt--xLB6U&index=16).

I am using a laptop with:

- NVIDIA GTX 1650 Max-Q design,
- 16 GB Ram,
- Intel i7 8th gen processor

Comment: have you checked what's your material settings? In Eevee, to get transparency you need to go into the Material > Settings > Blend Mode, choose Alpha Blend

Answer (score 0):

Make sure "Screen Space Refraction" is checked in the Settings menu on the Material tab.